# Add blinking network-monitor icon to GNOME / XFCE

Tags: networking, monitoring, xfce, icons, gnome-panel

I'd like to see if I have incoming or outgoing network traffic via a little blinking network-monitor icon in my system tray, similar to the network system tray icon in Windows XP and Android. I would like to replace that static icon that is used by default.

Is there a software package that can do this?

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Cross-posting is strongly discouraged -- if you post on one site and then change your mind it can always be migrated to another. unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting

Comment: I'm don't know XFCE, but Gnome2 and Gnome3 in classic mode has a panel applet called "System Monitor" that can be set to show a graph of that information, where you can choose the colors for each; I have green for incoming, and red for outgoing on mine.

Comment: @MartyFried oh i've seen the moving graph once. LXDE has it too, i think. That'll be a good, maybe a little edgy solution for gnome, thanks!